# Xamarin forms: I18n-portable casting error

Tags: xamarin.forms, internationalization

I'm working on a cross platform app using Xamarin forms in VS 2017, employing the I18n-portable NuGet-Package for internationalization (see http://xleon.net/localization/xamarin/pcl/share-locales/i18n/portable/dotnet/2017/02/09/easy-and-cross-platform-localization-for-xamarin-and-dotnet/). I got everything working so far, except for one thing.

Unfortunately, I am stuck on the last part where - according to the package readme - I need to create a proxy object on the baseviewmodel. I just don't know what to do here and no documentation on the web seems to help me with that.

What/where is the baseviewmodel?! Is it in `App.xaml.cs` of my example PCL solution? This is the code that the author of the package proposes to integrate:

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel
{
    public I18N Strings => I18N.Current; // causes error, see below
}
```

The code above causes an error when trying to integrate it as a new class:

Error CS0266: The type "I18NPortable.II18N" can't be implictly converted to "I18NPortable.I18N". There already exists an explicit conversion (conversion missing?).

Thanks for every hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `BaseViewModel` you will need to use an MVVM framework which is dependent on ViewModels. You then create a custom base class that your other view models inherit from which implements this. It is not something Xamarin hands you out of the box as MVVM is not a must when using Xamarin Forms and there are a number of MVVM frameworks out there.

The error you're getting basically says that the call to `I18N.Current` returns an object of type II18N which is an interface that you're assigning to an explicit type. You could try changing it to:

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel
{
    public II18N Strings => I18N.Current;
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for that information. Your suggested code change ehelped eliminating the error but did not solve the problem - translated string is still not displayed in the xamarin forms gui. Guess I'll keep on searching for something that works with Xamarin forms out of the box. Do not want to put another framework on top. Struggling already ;)

Comment: It looks like that I18N plugin should work. I have not tried it myself though. Perhaps its just a simple step you're missing? Try checking out their samples on Github, perhaps they can help you.

Comment: Yes it works for others and is supposed to be easy to use, but requires additional elements in the solution, such as MVVM, that I can't handle right now (C# and Xamarin forms newbie).

Comment: Besides, I'd like to build my user interfaces using XAML and not in C# code. The data binding for XAML seems to require a MVVM framework and that's where I'm still struggling with the basics. Ok, back to the books and tutorials then ;)

Comment: True. There's always Xamarin's own tutorial. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/ I don't think that uses MVVM necessarily. Getting the hang of MVVM will definitely increase your quality of life in the world of Xamarin though. Good luck!

Comment: Ok, I managed to get a FreshMvvM based Forms application running but still having problems integrating i18n-portable module into it. Did you manage to get it running or maybe know an online resource with further instructions apart from i18n-portable website? Been crawling the web for hours now but just can't find any appropriate info.

Comment: I'm using the code from the link above to the tutorial on Xamarins own site successfully in one of my own apps.

Comment: Ah ok, I figured I'd give i18n-module a chance as it looked pretty straight forward in the first place as opposed to the native xamarin way proposed by your link. Do you employ an MvvM framework?

Comment: I haven't tried i18n myself. Perhaps I'd prefer it over my current method but I just don't know yet. I use FreshMvvm as well for my projects.

Comment: According to https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/, the Resx properties shall be available via the AppResources class. For some strange reason I can't access the AppResources  class, no matter what. What do I have to include to access it!?

Comment: It depends on where your Resx files reside. If you open up your AppResources.designer.cs file you should be able to see the namespace and classname where it is hanging out.

Comment: They reside in a "Resx" folder, named AppResources.en.resx for instance. I was expecting the AppResources class to be available globally so can access it from other files such as an arbitrary XAML page .cs file like this: AppResources.LabelName but I can't no matter what I prepend. I am missing something crucial...